# How can I select one plot from the partial dependence plot in R?

Tags: r, random-forest

Here is the code for the partial dependence plot. I use the example data for this. First of all, I made a random forest model. Then I made a partial dependence plot.

```
rm(list = ls())

library(tidyverse)
library(mlbench)
library(randomForest)
library(caret)
library(edarf)

data("Sonar")
df<-Sonar
rm(Sonar)

# Clean up variable names (becuz I'm a bit OCD)
df <- df %>% rename(V01 = V1, V02 = V2, V03 = V3, V04 = V4, 
                    V05 = V5, V06 = V6, V07 = V7, V08 = V8,
                    V09 = V9)
# Get minimum class frequency
min <- min(table(df$Class))

set.seed(223)
df_rf <- df %>% na.omit()

fit_rf <- randomForest(data = df_rf, 
                       Class ~ .,
                       ntree = 500,
                       importance = TRUE,
                       sampsize = c(min, min))

# Add predicted values to data frame
df_rf <- df_rf %>% 
  mutate(predicted = predict(fit_rf))
# Get performance measures
confusionMatrix(df_rf$predicted, df_rf$Class, positive = "R")

# Get variable importance measures
imp_df <- data.frame(importance(fit_rf, scale = FALSE, type = 1))

# Tidy up and sort the data frame
imp_df <- imp_df %>% 
  mutate(names = rownames(imp_df)) %>% 
  arrange(desc(MeanDecreaseAccuracy))

# Save top predictor names as character vector
nm <- as.character(imp_df$names)[1:10]
# Get partial depedence values for top predictors
pd_df <- partial_dependence(fit = fit_rf,
                            vars = nm,
                            data = df_rf,
                            n = c(100, 200))
# Plot partial dependence using edarf
plot_pd(pd_df)
```

Then I got the result as follows.

[image]

I successfully got the multiple images that combined as one big plot. However, I need to select any one of these plots. Is there any way I can try?

Comment: @MrFlick Thank you for your feedback. I just revised my questions by adding some codes for this. I removed the shiny tag. Choosing any single graph is okay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the dataframe your `pd_df` where you first have to make it a longer format by the columns M and R to visualize it in ggplot by a variable you want like this with example of V11:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
pd_df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = c(M, R)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = V11, y = value, color = name)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() +
  labs(x = "value", y = "prediction")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-01-09 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

You can replace V11 with other variables like you want.